# Zeroes of infinite product function?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, infinite-product

Given an entire function $\prod_{n=0}^∞ E_n (\frac{z}{z_n})$ , show that $(z_n )_n∈N$ is a complete list of the zeroes of this function in which each zero appears as many times as its multiplicity.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry, I neglected to mention that $E_n(z) = (1 − z)e^{z+\frac{z^2}{2}+...+\frac{z^n}{n}}$ where n is a positive integer.

Comment: I have rectified this. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not enough time to answer.  Note that the $(1-z)$ factors give (for the $N^\text{th}$ partial product) a polynomial with zeroes exactly as expected, the exponentials are truncations of $\mathrm{e}^{\ln(1-z)}$, and you need to show that the exponentials stay far enough away from $0$ that their product(s) don't induce extra zeroes -- maybe you have a criterion for convergence that helps you here?